# jQuery Text Editor Font Background

Tags: jquery, jqte

I'm using jQuery Text Editor, but I couldn't find a way to change the selected text background. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Show us what you have and explain what you have tried, or you won't get any help.

Comment: exist billion solutions in web, just use search. Take this http://jsfiddle.net/f9k10633/

Comment: Sorry guy for the late reply...I didn't explain correctly what I want. I want to highlight a text, with jqte there's a button to change the text color, I need another button to highlight the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
::selection {
  background: #ffb7b7;
}
```

First google example: http://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/

Answer (score 0):

the other answers seem to be about what color shows up *as* you highlight text.

jqte doesn't seem to actually have a simple way to change highlighting/the text background! The best bet I've found is using source/html view and manually adding:

`<span style="background-color: yellow;">highlighted text</span>`